# Protected Property Of Parent Class

Tags: c#

I am using a parent class property called "Contribuable" and then I called in a derived class called "ContribuableMoral" during execution but it appears to me in the null derived class method.

```
public class contribuable
{
    protected string MATRICULE_FISCALE;

    public contribuable(string _matricule_fiscale)
    {
        this.MATRICULE_FISCALE = _matricule_fiscale; //example MATRICULE_FISCALE=123456789
    }

    public void insertContribuable()
    {
        string sql = "insert into CLIENT(MATRICULE_FISCALE)values('" +this.MATRICULE_FISCALE +"')"; //MATRICULE_FISCALE=123456789
    }
}
}

class ContribuableMoral : contribuable
{
    public ContribuableMoral()
    {
    }

    public void InsertionMorale()
    {
        string sqlMorale = "insert into CLIENT_MORALE(MATRICULE_FISCALE) values('" + MATRICULE_FISCALE + "')"; //MATRICULE_FISCALE=null
    }
}
```

Normally ownership relatives told the class can be called to the derived class?

Comment: What does the debugger say? What is the error?

Comment: Such an awful code decoration: lower-case class name, no horizontal indentation, no vertical spacing, randomly located curly braces. In addition to SQL-Injection-vulnerable code due to string concatenation.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I suspect that is the source of errors..

Comment: This codes would not even compile.. Missing backets, brackets at wrong places, etc.

Comment: You have to work on your formatting. Now, I have done it for you, but it was an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Ian never edit the code in the question to fix it. Answers are for code fixes!

Comment: @PatrickHofman my apologize. I did not realize that you left it on purpose. Please reject my edit.

Comment: I already did. Need two more to reject it. No problem :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thank you for editing my answer. Using single `'` quotes for strings is the bad JS habit. Happily, it occurs only when giving answers at SO, not when coding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, code like this won't compile in the first place..
But the problem is that your derived class does not have constructor for base class that would pass _matricule_fiscale.
Add constructor:

```
public ContribuableMoral(string _matricule_fiscale) : base (_matricule_fiscale) { }
```

to ContribuableMoral class.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a parameter for the constructor that you pass in the parent class, for example:

```
public ContribuableMoral(string _matricule_fiscale) : base(_matricule_fiscale)
```

Then it will work and also there are some other errors.

Below classes fixed:

```
public class contribuable
{
    protected string MATRICULE_FISCALE;

    public contribuable(string _matricule_fiscale)
    {
        this.MATRICULE_FISCALE = _matricule_fiscale; //example MATRICULE_FISCALE=123456789}

    }
    public void insertContribuable()
    {
        string sql = "insert into CLIENT(MATRICULE_FISCALE)values('" + this.MATRICULE_FISCALE + "')";
        //MATRICULE_FISCALE=123456789
    }
}

internal class ContribuableMoral : contribuable
{
    public ContribuableMoral(string _matricule_fiscale) : base(_matricule_fiscale)
    {
    }

    public void InsertionMorale()
    {
        string sqlMorale = "insert into CLIENT_MORALE(MATRICULE_FISCALE) values('" + MATRICULE_FISCALE + "')";
        //MATRICULE_FISCALE=null
    }
}
```

To call this use:

```
var c = new ContribuableMoral("123456789");
c.InsertionMorale();
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your `Contribuable` parametrized constructor isn't called from `ContribuableMoral`.

It should be either:

```
class ContribuableMoral : Contribuable 
{
    public ContribuableMoral() : base("somestring")
    {
    }
```

or

```
class ContribuableMoral : Contribuable 
{
    public ContribuableMoral(string matriculeFiscale) : base(matriculeFiscale)
    {
    }
```

**Note 1**: please, review the following code style and format your code in the similar way in order to make other people understand you.

```
public class Contribuable
{
    protected string MatriculeFiscale { get; }

    public Contribuable(string matriculeFiscale)
    {
        MatriculeFiscale = matriculeFiscale; 
    }

    public void InsertContribuable()
    {
        string sql = "insert into CLIENT(MATRICULE_FISCALE)values('" + MatriculeFiscale  +"')";
    }   
}

class ContribuableMoral : Contribuable 
{
    public ContribuableMoral(string matriculeFiscale) : base(matriculeFiscale)
    {
    }

    public void InsertionMorale()
    {
        string sqlMorale = "insert into CLIENT_MORALE(MATRICULE_FISCALE) values('" + MatriculeFiscale + "')";
    }
}
```

**Note 2:** Your code is now vulnerable to SQL injections. Do not use string concatenation for building SQL queries.